# Changing local function so it can be used globally

Tags: javascript, html

I have a test function that currently formats and tests a credit card number as it is being input

I need to make it so instead of using `document.getElementById("cc")` I can use a variable that's passed to the function which is equal to the id of the text box and will still change what is in the textbox

```
<script>
Function ReplacingImage() {
    var str = document.getElementById("cc").value;
    var strTest = str.charAt(0);
    switch(strTest) {
            case "3":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/amex.png"
                    break;
            case "4":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/visa.png"
                    break;
            case "5":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/mastercard.png"
                    break;
            case "6":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/discover.png"
                    break;
            case "":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/none.png"
                    break;
            default:
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/invalid.png"
                    break;
    }

    var strNoSpace = str;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < (strNoSpace.length / "4"); i++) {
            strNoSpace = strNoSpace.replace(" ", "");
    }

    var lastDig = strNoSpace.substring(strNoSpace.length - 1, strNoSpace.length);

    if(isNaN(lastDig)) { document.getElementById("cc").value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);  }

    if((strNoSpace.length > 16 && (strTest == "4" || strTest == "5" || strTest == "6")) || (strNoSpace.length > 15 && (strTest == "3"))) {
            document.getElementById("cc").value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    } else if((strNoSpace.length == "15" && strTest == "3") || (strNoSpace.length == "16" && (strTest == "4" || strTest == "5" || strTest == "6"))) {
            value = document.getElementById("cc").value;
            if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)) {
                    document.getElementById("cc").style.color = "red";
            }


            let nCheck = 0, bEven = false;
            value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

            for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
                    var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
                              nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

                    if (bEven && (nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;

                    nCheck += nDigit;
                    bEven = !bEven;
            }

            if((nCheck % 10) != 0) {
                    document.getElementById("cc").style.color = "red";
            }
            else {
                    document.getElementById("cc").style.color = "green";
            }

    } else {
            document.getElementById("cc").style.color = "black";
    }


    if(strNoSpace.length > 15 && (strTest == "3")) { document.getElementById("cc").value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1); }

    if(!isNaN(lastDig) && strNoSpace.length != "0" && (strNoSpace.length % 
"4") == "0" && strNoSpace.length < "16" && event.keyCode != "8") {
            document.getElementById("cc").value += " ";
    }
}
</script>
```

This function is called by the onkeyup of a text box like so

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="ReplacingImage()" title="CC of Customer" id="cc" name="cc" placeholder="###"/>
```

Comment: I think `this` could be used here. I was here for the PHP though so can't help much with JS.

Comment: <input onkeyup=“replaceimage(this.id)” id=“cc”>

Comment: Please add the text which defines a `ReplacingImage` function to your code

Comment: @jalanb The ReplacingImage function is the first block of code, I included that in there to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ReplacingImage(id) {
console.log(id);


    var str = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var strTest = str.charAt(0);
    console.log(str);
    switch(strTest) {
            case "3":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/amex.png"
                    break;
            case "4":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/visa.png"
                    break;
            case "5":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/mastercard.png"
                    break;
            case "6":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/discover.png"
                    break;
            case "":
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/none.png"
                    break;
            default:
                    document.getElementById("x").src="/common/cc-images/invalid.png"
                    break;
    }

    var strNoSpace = str;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < (strNoSpace.length / "4"); i++) {
            strNoSpace = strNoSpace.replace(" ", "");
    }

    var lastDig = strNoSpace.substring(strNoSpace.length - 1, strNoSpace.length);

    if(isNaN(lastDig)) { document.getElementById(id").value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);  }

    if((strNoSpace.length > 16 && (strTest == "4" || strTest == "5" || strTest == "6")) || (strNoSpace.length > 15 && (strTest == "3"))) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    } else if((strNoSpace.length == "15" && strTest == "3") || (strNoSpace.length == "16" && (strTest == "4" || strTest == "5" || strTest == "6"))) {
            value = document.getElementById(id").value;
            if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)) {
                    document.getElementById(id").style.color = "red";
            }


            let nCheck = 0, bEven = false;
            value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

            for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
                    var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
                              nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

                    if (bEven && (nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;

                    nCheck += nDigit;
                    bEven = !bEven;
            }

            if((nCheck % 10) != 0) {
                    document.getElementById(id").style.color = "red";
            }
            else {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
            }

    } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
    }


    if(strNoSpace.length > 15 && (strTest == "3")) { document.getElementById(id).value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1); }

    if(!isNaN(lastDig) && strNoSpace.length != "0" && (strNoSpace.length % 
"4") == "0" && strNoSpace.length < "16" && event.keyCode != "8") {
            document.getElementById(id).value += " ";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="ReplacingImage(this.id)" title="CC of Customer" id="cc" name="cc" placeholder="###">
```

Comment: Noticed some syntax that needed fixing, but otherwise worked great!